# how to fetch azure serviceconnection name from variablegroup in azure pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops

I need to fetch serviceconnection name from variable group in the pipeline
pipeline details

```
   variables:
   - group: abcd # groupname
```

task where fetching the variables from the variable group

```
- task: AzureFunctionApp@1
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: $(azure-subscription)
    appType: 'functionApp'
    appName: '$(PROJECTNAME)-$(LOCATION)-${{ parameters.componentName }}-${{ parameters.environment }}'
    package: '$(APPCODEARCHIVE)'
    deploymentMethod: 'auto'
```

I am getting below error mentioned in the screenshot
[image]

Comment: So if your service connection is created then you would need it to authorize it. Please click on **Authorize resources** and see if it helps. You would need `Endpoint Administrator Access` to do so.

Comment: if i pass the service connection name insted of variable it is working.  That means it is already authorized. Here the problem is it is not substituting the value in the task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my test scenario, if I define the variable group at job level, I am facing the same auth issue.

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

# variables:
# - group: New variable group 16-Nov

stages:
  - stage: test
    jobs:
      - job: A
        variables:
         - group: New variable group 16-Nov
        steps:
          - task: AzureFunctionApp@1
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: '$(az-test)'
              appType: 'functionApp'
              appName: 'test'
              package: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/*.zip'
              deploymentMethod: 'auto'
```

[image]

It works when I define the variable group at root level.

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

variables:
- group: New variable group 16-Nov

stages:
  - stage: test
    jobs:
      - job: A
        # variables:
        #  - group: New variable group 16-Nov
        steps:
          - task: AzureFunctionApp@1
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: '$(az-test)'
              appType: 'functionApp'
              appName: 'test'
              package: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/*.zip'
              deploymentMethod: 'auto'
```

[image]